# How to run wget inside Ubuntu Docker image?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wget

I'm trying to download a Debian package inside a Ubuntu container as follows:

```
sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu-14.04/gitlab_7.8.2-omnibus.1-1_amd64.deb
```

I get

```
exec: "wget": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I've already installed `wget` with docker as follows:

```
run ubuntu:14.04 apt-get install wget
```

How can I download a file?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You need to install it first. Create a new `Dockerfile`, and install wget in it:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then, build that image:

```
docker build -t my-ubuntu .
```

Finally, run it:

```
docker run my-ubuntu wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu-14.04/gitlab_7.8.2-omnibus.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: @Nachbar90 Each `docker run` command runs in an isolated container, so, whatever you installed in the first container isn't going to be present in the second container. You should probably read up a bit more on what containers are and how they work.

Comment: How can you forward the result file of the last run to your local file system?

Comment: It works fine but I wanted to ask about the package version. Otherwise, it doesnt pass the docker lint .

Comment: Hi @ThomasOrozco. Why do you remove this folder /var/lib/apt/lists ?

Answer (score 61):

I had this problem recently where `apt install wget` does not find anything. As it turns out `apt update` was never run.

```
apt update
apt install wget
```

After discussing this with a coworker we mused that `apt update` is likely not run in order to save both time and space in the docker image.

Comment: had installed docker ubuntu container by simply doing docker pulll ubuntu and later into bash, got a "apt not found issue". This worked for me .thanks

Comment: so helpful! I did this in centos7 docker container to get ping command working. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you're running ubuntu container directly without a local Dockerfile you can ssh into the container and enable root control by entering `su` then `apt-get install -y wget`