# Docker: forward container run environment, such as files, std IO, to local filesystem?

Tags: docker, io, filesystems, stdout, stdin

You get some results in a docker run, such as a file, stdout or stderr. You want to forward them to your local file system or some other file system, such as cloud file system.

*Steps.*

1. You build a docker container such as wget as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28885237/164148).
2. You run it: `docker run my-ubuntu wget http://google.com`

   ```
   2018-07-17 15:57:35 (57.9 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [11657]
   ```

*How can I access that `index.html` in my local file system? How can I forward stdout or stderr from the container to my own shell?*

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `WORKDIR` directive to your Dockerfile, for instance

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /tmp
```

And then run your image using the volume switch to mount a host location to the containers `WORKDIR`.  For instance:

```
docker run -v /home/me:/tmp my-ubuntu wget http://google.com
```

Then `index.html` would be downloaded to /tmp within the container and available at /home/me/index.html on your local file system.